# Outputting JSON data as table and using Javascript to replace linebreaks with <br />

Tags: javascript, json

I'm loading JSON data and outputting it dynamically into a table as follows:

```
<p id="showData"></p>

<script>

    var myData = <?php echo $formdata; ?>

    //columns to be displayed
    let displayColumns = ['label', 'type', 'userData'];

    //filter data
     myData = myData.map(x => {
      let newObj = {};
      for (col of displayColumns) {
        newObj[col] = x[col];
      }
      return newObj;
    });

    // values for headers
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
      for (var key in myData[i]) {
        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          col.push(key);
        }
      }
    }
    // the table
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    // create headers
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    // add rows
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);


        if (myData[i][col[j]] == null) {
            myData[i][col[j]] = '';
        }

        var mycontent = myData[i][col[j]];

        tabCell.innerHTML = mycontent;

      }
    }
    // Output
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);

</script>
```

All works very nicely, except that \r \n breaks in the JSON are rendered as white space, and ignored by the browser.

I thought I could just use:

```
mycontent.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

My JSON data looks like this:

[{"type":"textarea","required":false,"label":"Text Area","className":"fo

```
rm-control","name":"textarea-1587413609222","subtype":"textarea","userData":["This is an example with a linebreak\r\n\r\nRight below"]},{"type":"textarea","required":false,"label":"Text Area","className":"form-control","name":"textarea-1587413619910","subtype":"textarea","userData":["And another\r\n\r\nAnd another"]},{"type":"textarea","required":false,"label":"Text Area","className":"form-control","name":"textarea-1587413619231","subtype":"textarea","userData":["But this has none"]}]

Where am I going wrong?
```

Comment: Wrap json into `<pre><code>` tags.

Comment: you cannot use .replace function on array directly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

```
var mycontent = myData[i][col[j]];
if(Array.isArray(mycontent) && mycontent.length === 1)
   mycontent = mycontent[0];
```

then you can use replace and it will work.

because this is an array:

```
"userData":[
   "And another\r\n\r\nAnd another"
]
```

Comment: Ahhh, perfect. Silly me. Will give it a go. Thanks